# Redirect loop on rails with admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Admin::SessionsController who extends from Admin::ApplicationController.
I'm using a before_filter except to the login page, but the server is entering in a loop
I think there`s is something with the except thing, I think that I need to set the namespace or something...

This is the line of before_filte:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user ,  :except => { :sessions => :new }
```

This is my SessionController

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
    def new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest just to put a skip_before_filter in the Admin:SessionsController

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:new]

  def new
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks... I did that, but with skip_filter and not skip_before_filter... thanks dude!